# cannot install nvidia driver , In function 'block_cpu_fault_locked': error implicit declaration of function 'task_stack_page

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, x11, nvidia

I am trying to re-install Ubuntu and NVIDIA driver on my desktop computer after a computer crash. But the NVIDIA driver cannot successfully install after the crash. The first problem was the computer goes to low resolution mode after Ubuntu usb installation asks me to 'restart' the computer. The second problem I encountered was the screen goes to a black screen after I switch to text command mode by pressing ctrl-alt-F1.  I learned to solve the black screen text command mode by editing  `/etc/default/grub` and add 'nomodeset' to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable and reboot the computer.

I then download https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/384.130/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.130.run  and install this NVIDIA driver. But the installation failed due to the following error:

> /tmp/selfgz1982/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.130/krenel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_block.c:
>   In funcion 'block_cpu_fault_locked':
>   ./arch/x86/inlcude/asm/process.h:820:39: error implicit declaration of
>   function 'task_stack_page' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>   unsigned long __ptr = (unsigned long)task_stack_page(task);

Is the graphic card broken?
Does nvidia drive change mother bias or graphic card setting when it crashs?
Ubuntu installation can finish installation and show nice resolution.

Is there any suggestion I can do to fix it ?

Comment: What linux kernel are you using? (`uname -a`)

Answer (score 8):

As @Wang pointed out, here's the solution: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/33284#issuecomment-354672627

Now, if you are using a script `nvidia.run`, it might be a bit tricky because the script extracts source code, runs, and erases the source code afterward. Here's how you can overcome it:

1. `sudo ./nvidia.run -x` will extract the source code.
2. Locate the extracted folder. Inside, there is a file `[the-extracted-folder]/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_block.c`. Add `#include <linux/sched/task_stack.h>` to the top.
3. `sudo [the-extracted-folder]/nvidia-installer` to install the driver.

Then, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

It is a known [issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/33284):

> Adding `#include <linux/sched/task_stack.h>` on top of
> `kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_block.c` should fix the issue.

Comment: I was able to reinstall ubuntu and nvidia driver a few days ago.  Except one mother board, the others do mot work properly.  You said  thud is a "now issue". Doo you mean this just happen？ Does every body have the same issue？https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/384.98/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.98.run is an old version.

Comment: https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/384.98/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.98.run    is an exe file. It unpacks and compiles thr driver. It seems if the installation fails，the program erases all source codes.  I got no chance to include the .h file mannually.  Is there any other script that allows me to add the  .h  file?

Comment: See my answer. You just need to perform a few more steps.

Comment: On Ubuntu you'll want to update `/usr/src/nvidia-387-387.26/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_block.c`. At least that worked for me on `artful`.

Comment: If you go back to the open source driver (which is fine for kicad etc) you can get a real problem with this. The Nvidia can black list the old driver and when uninstalled leaves the blacklist file in place leaving you with a low res screen. The way to fix it is to go to /etc/modprobe.d and look for a file named something like nvidia_graphics_drivers....conf. Either delete this or rename it to something without .conf at the end. reboot. enjoy your open source driver.

Answer (score 1):

To extract use

```
sudo sh cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux.run --extract=$home/Downloads/cuda
```

Comment: If you go back to the open source driver (which is fine for kicad etc) you can get a real problem with this. The Nvidia can black list the old driver and when uninstalled leaves the blacklist file in place leaving you with a low res screen. The way to fix it is to go to /etc/modprobe.d and look for a file named something like nvidia_graphics_drivers....conf. Either delete this or rename it to something without .conf at the end. reboot. enjoy your open source driver.